# Difference btw org.hibernate.jmx.HibernateService and org.jboss.hibernate.jmx.Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jndi

Both of them are mbeans. Both are intended to setup Hibernate Session Factory and expose it through JNDI. Both are implemented in Red Hat. But at the same time each of them belongs to separate classes hierarchy.

What is actually the difference between them?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `org.hibernate.jmx.HibernateService` is part of core Hibernate
- `org.jboss.hibernate.jmx.Hibernate` is not part of the core but part of JBoss. It seems to be a historic thing - probably from when Hibernate did not have an MBean.  It seems to be [due to be removed](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-2907).